# Do event creation and reponse methods have restrictions or standards in C#?

Tags: c#, events, parameters, delegates, keyword

I know how to use delegates and events in C#. However, there are a couple of things I do not know.

If I have a conditional method and a response method, are there restrictions for the parameters for those methods?

Do I have to have certain types of parameters or a certain number of parameters for those methods?

Are there rules on what type of keywords I can put in front of the method names?

Is there a standard for parameter types, number of parameters, and the keywords associated with the methods?

I know the standard keywords for conditional methods is protected virtual void. However, I do not know what the standard keywords for response methods are.

Comment: Conditional methods?  Do you mean https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288458%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 ?

Comment: No, when it comes to events in C sharp, you have one method that sets the condition for the second method to be run. That is why I call the first method a conditional method.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard events explained in such a way.  An event is fired when object invokes a delegate which has been exposed as an event on the object.   I think you're creating your own terminology which is a little confusing and probably why your question didn't get answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to the

```
protected void OnClicked(EventArgs e)
{
....
```

I've never heard this referred to as a conditional method.  The scoping protected virtual void is convention.  I believe the idea is that internally an object inheriting another class exposing an event should override these methods instead of consuming the events.  Also if a derived class needs to invoke the event it should be able to do so by called the OnClicked method.

There's no convention on code which consumes events, if this method doesn't need to be invoked externally it can be private....

e.g

```
...
myObject.Clicked += myObject_Clicked;  // Consume the event
...

private void myObject_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// hand onclicked
}
```

For further guidance....

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx